# Full proof check for java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android

Tags: android, null, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception

Still getting *java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 length=0* error in the code below at `if (result.charAt(0) =='Y')`

Is there any other better way to check for null strings at `if (result == null || result.isEmpty())` ? For some reason the null string "result" was not picked up or `activity.finish();` did not execute and the next if statement was executed? Any help please.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //check if result null or empty
        if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Could Not Check For Updates, Please Try Again. Closing Application.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
        }           
        //update available
        if (result.charAt(0) =='Y') {

            UpdateAlert();
        }
        //no update available
        else if (result.charAt(0) =='N') {

            Toast.makeText(context, "No Updates Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Could Not Check For Updates, Please Try Again. Closing Application : " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
        }
```

Comment: Try to accept your suitable answers to get more vicinity for your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if (result == null || result.trim().length()==0) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Could Not Check For Updates, Please Try Again. Closing  Application.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
        }           
        //update available
        else if (result.charAt(0) =='Y') {
        ^^^^ 
            UpdateAlert();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return from the method once encountering invalid result as modified below

```
//check if result null or empty         
           if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {              
                Toast.makeText(context, "Could Not Check For Updates, Please Try Again. Closing Application.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
                activity.finish();         
                return;
           }
```